# How can I make a 3D button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a button with black background but no shadow. When I click the front button, yellow button's x, y and z coordinates should move to black button's coordinates. How can I make a button like this. Thank you.

[image]